# Django Python, javascript will not send requests - very simple code

Tags: javascript, python, django, url, cloud

I've been trying to send a variable through JS in HTML using my views url.

I have a super super simple API which looks like this (views.py). As you can see it literally takes anything in and slaps it into the updated field. So if you were to visit that page it shows the last thing posted.

```
def store(request):
   req = str(request)
   l=len(req)
   if l > 28:
      Storage.objects.last().delete()
      q = Storage(data=req[26:l-2])
      q.save()
   link = Storage.objects.last()
   return render_to_response('crophop/imgur.html',{'link':link})
```

I have then done this to pass the number 100, for the webpage to store it.

```
<script>var URL = "{% url 'store' %}"</script>

<html stuff....>

<script>
   $.get(URL, '100', function(response){
       if(response === 'success'){ alert('Yay!'); }
       else{ alert('Error! :('); }
   };
</script>
```

I've tried so many versions of this, I don't know why js wont comply. I know I can't access external URLs easily so I thought this was the best way. I've seen many posts on this and tried as many as I found but I'm still stuck...

If anyone has any ideas why this doesn't work I'd be grateful. It seems like it's so basic it should work, it might be something to do with pythonanywhere.com?

Thanks,

Fred

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: Do you see this http call in the browser's inspector window?

Comment: There's not really enough information to give you an answer.  Are you seeing javascript errors on the page?  Does the page try to make the call and it gets an error or does it not even try to make the call?

Comment: There are lots of very strange things in this code. Why do you turn the request into a string and then delete items if it's more than 28 chars long? The str out a request will be something like `<HttpRequest: blah>`, why do you care how long it is?

Comment: Yes - it gives an error so I think it tries to make the call. But for whatever reason it doesn't complete it?

I refresh my page, it runs the js, and I get the error pop up.

Too latest comment: If you cut it off at 28 it means everything outside of the wgsi request wrapping is taken into account. E.g. if I do a request it says <wgsi-request/store/blahblah>      If I do what I've done it only gives me blahblah.

Essentially some(thing) e.g. an esp8266 ;) can look at the page and get information from it, whilst something else can update it via request.

Inspector window Ill check it out

Comment: That's *really* not the way to do it. Use the attributes and methods that the request object gives you.

Answer (score 0):

5 open brackets.

4 close brackets.

1 thing missed.

Lots of wasted time.

:(